# 1.5 V LDO regulator for lithium-ion cell conversion

Tags: dc-motor, lithium-ion, battery-operated, ldo

TL:DR: I want to power a 1.2 V motor with a lithium-ion cell.

I have a electric shaver and a trimmer that uses a 1.2 V NiCd battery cell.
I'm surprised that, in 2022, I can still buy NiCd battery device with no over charge protection. Now The NiCd battery died and I want to convert to lithium-ion.

Due to space constraints, I figure the easiest way is to use a LDO regulator + 2 capacitors.
The motor is believe to be 1.2 V 300 mA.
I have tried various 1.2 V and 1.5 V LDO regulators (500 mA TLV755P; 400 mA TPS736) but the motor always has trouble starting (runs maybe 1 out of 10 tries).

I figure it could be the high start up current of a motor, which could be 4~6 times of rated current. (probably should connect to a DC power supply and figure out the current draw?)

Should I get a 1 A, 1.5 A, or 3 A LDO regulator?
A 1.2 V 1 A LDO regulator, will it be output Constant V OR Constant C?

Comment: Guessing the motor to be mechanically commutated, you could try PWM, starting at about 0.35.

Comment: A very dumb solution would be a series resistor of 4 ohm / 1 W with a capacitor of 470 uF parallel to the resistor for the startup current.

Comment: You did not say is the battery is AAA, AA or a special size. A Ni-MH battery cell is available with the same voltage as Ni-Cad and can be charged by the Ni-Cad charger.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a voltage regulator, consider a DC motor controller. It handles the peak current at start-up, it limits the torque, and it sets the desired running voltage. You can find DC motor controller nodules online under the name "ESC" (Electronic Speed Control).

Comment: I now see why many DIY EV car video install a controller, ESC that is... but I don't think any ESC will fit. Using LDO to began with is for its simplicity..